# Change name of surefire-report that android-maven-plugin outputs

Tags: android, maven, surefire, android-maven-plugin

I can't find any way to change the name of the surefire-report that uiautomator together with android-maven-plugin outputs.

Anyone know if its possible? Or any work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant the `TEST-<STUFF>.xml` files with test report, then this is not configurable, refer to https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jayway/maven/plugins/android/standalonemojos/UIAutomatorMojo.java, `writeJunitReportToFile()` method (or just search for "TEST-" pattern).

A workaround might be moving the report files with [antrun](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/).

Comment: Thank you, I looked into the code and noticed this as well. Thank you for workaround alternative!

Comment: I just submitted a pull request to maven-android-plugin. I added the parameter reportSuffix to UIAutomator.